# points border color and line color is different between legend box and whole plot box when pch=21

Tags: r, plot

**ENV**

MACOSX 10.9.4 
R 3.3.1

[image]

**My problem**

The border color of point in legend is green4. But the border color of points for whole plot is black. See the figure above, in the plot box there are three points and line color is green4, the point border is black and the points background is red. However, in the legend box which is on topright the line color is green4, the point background is red, *the point border color* is **not black** which is green4 same with the line in legend box.

If you add `col` in legend, the point border color in legend box is changed and at the same time the line color in legend box is changed either.

**MY current code is below**:

```
initial.dir<-getwd()
setwd("/works/bin")
sink("r.o")
pk <- read.table("2017.info")
rownames(pk)<-c("k","pk")
d.f <- data.frame(t(pk))

pdf(file="5000-max.pdf")

plot(
  d.f$k,
  d.f$pk,
  type = "n",
  log = "xy",
  main = "Degree distribution",
  xlab = "k",
  ylab = "p(k)",
  xlim = c( 10^0, 10^2),
  ylim = c( 0.00001, 1),
  xaxt="n", yaxt="n",
  xaxs="i", yaxs="i",
)

lines( d.f$k, d.f$pk, col = "green4", lty = "solid")
points( d.f$k, d.f$pk, bg = "red", pch = 21 )
legend("topright", inset=.05, c("p(k)"), lty="solid", pch=21, col=c("green4"), pt.bg="red")

axis(side = 1, at = 10^(0:2), labels = expression(10^0, 10^1, 10^2))
axis(side = 2, at = 10^(-5:0), labels = expression(10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0))

abline(h=outer((1:10),(10^(-5:-1))), col="#00000033", lty=2)
abline(v=outer((1:10),(10^(0:1))), col="#00000033", lty=2)

box()
dev.off

sink()
setwd(initial.dir)
```

**What I expected is**

The line color, points border color, points background color in the plot should be same with the legend.

How should I changed my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change the color of point borders in the chart, I would change

```
points( d.f$k, d.f$pk, bg = "red", pch = 21 )
```

to

```
points( d.f$k, d.f$pk, bg = "red", col = "green4",pch = 21 )
```

To change the color in the legend just change

```
legend("topright", inset=.05, c("p(k)"), lty="solid", pch=21, col=c("green4"), pt.bg="red")
```

To

```
legend("topright", inset=.05, c("p(k)"), lty="solid", pch=21, col=c"black", pt.bg="red")
```

Comment: When you changed `col` in legend, the line color in legend and the point border color in legend both changed at same time. In the plot, I can use `lines` function to change line color and I can use `points` function to change points border color and points background color. So that the line color, point border color, point background color in the plot are three different color. I mean that is it possible to changed the line color and point color separately in legend box? Say, in legend box the line color is green4 and the point border color is black and the point background color is red.