# R specifying point border color differently from fill and line

Tags: r, legend

This is related to [points border color and line color is different between legend box and whole plot box when pch=21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922571/points-border-color-and-line-color-is-different-between-legend-box-and-whole-plo)

I have a plot with filled point (pch=21), black border and green filled, but I also have whiskers for the error that are the same color as the fill color. I know I can match the point in the legend using a combination of "col" and "pt.bg", but then the line color matches the point border, which is not what I need:

```
x=1:10
y=runif(10)
plot(x,y,lwd=3,col="black",bg="green",pch=21,cex=2)
arrows(x,y-0.05,x,y+0.05,lwd=3,col="green",angle=90,code=3)
legend(5,0.8,col="black",pt.bg="green",lwd=3,pch=21,legend="text",cex=2)
```

gives the following...

[image]

Is there a way of having legend green lines and green filled points with the point border black?  Even nicer would be having the whiskers, but I think that is probably not possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two `legend` calls. One to plot the line with `bg = NA` and the other to plot the point with `bty = "n"`:

```
set.seed(1)
x=1:10
y=runif(10)
plot(x, y, lwd = 3, col = "black", bg = "green", pch = 21, cex = 2)
arrows(x, y-0.05, x, y+0.05, lwd = 3, col = "green", angle = 90, code = 3)
legend("topright",
       col="green",
       lwd = 3,
       lty = 1,
       legend = "text",
       cex = 2,
       bg = NA)
legend("topright",
       col = "black",
       pt.bg = "green",
       pch = 21,
       lwd = 3,
       legend = "text",
       cex = 2,
       lty = 0,
       bty = "n")
```

[image]